# Changing XSL View not working

Tags: sharepoint-designer, xslt, url, xslt-list-view-web-part, image

I have on my site a Business Data Connectivity list with a field which equals some urls.

I found some internet links to change the url text to the image which the text points on. But it's not working.

This is my list:

[image]

And these are the fields with the text url:

```
<td class="ms-vb">
    <xsl:attribute name="style">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$dvt_1_form_selectkey = @*[name()=$ColumnKey]">color:blue</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise />
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:variable name="fieldValue">
      <xsl:call-template name="LFtoBR">
        <xsl:with-param name="input">
          <xsl:value-of select="@url" />
        </xsl:with-param>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:copy-of select="$fieldValue" />
  </td>
```

What should I change to show the text from the url field as a picture which the url points on?

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you selected the field type as [Hyperlink or Picture](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Site-column-types-and-options-0d8ddb7b-7dc7-414d-a283-ee9dca891df7?CorrelationId=2127b9fa-c5a7-4e12-957e-e0f08bffee6c&ui=en-US&rs=en-AU&ad=AU#__toc277149830) and selected the option, 'Picture'

Comment: Where can i format the field as such a Hyperlink or Picture in a BCS List?

Comment: Go to the list definition and then to the column definition. You should have an option to choose 'Picture'